# Rename artifacts to sha256-filename.file with sha256sum in jenkins groovy

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I need to rename artifacts in jenkins. What I want is like sha256lksjdfj0wij423480u2-file.txt I Have tried with this before archiving it:

```
stage('Rename SHA')
{
    sh """#!/bin/bash
    mv ${WORKSPACE}/proj/file.txt ${WORKSPACE}/proj/$(sha256sum file.txt| cut -d" " -f1)-file.txt"
    """
}
```

But gets this error message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: file for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using triple double-quoted string, so Groovy tries to interpolate all token started with `$`. To avoid that, replace `$` with `\$`:

```
sh """#!/bin/bash
    mv ${WORKSPACE}/proj/file.txt ${WORKSPACE}/proj/\$(sha256sum file.txt| cut -d" " -f1)-file.txt"
"""
```

Note `\$(sha256sum`...